# Nicest way to write a class that contains multiples enums with common fields

Tags: java, enums, field

Let's assume that I have a class Test, which contains multiples enums. Theses contains always the same fields, and have one common constructor. What can be the nicest way to refactor this ?

Thank you. I saw some similar topics but I didn't saw that case.

Here is my code :

```
public final class Test{

    public enum A {
         MyField1("1", "2"),
         MyField2("3", "4"),
         MyField3("5", "6"),

         private final String key;
         private final String shortcut;

         A(String k, String s){ 
             this.key= k;
             this.shortcut= s;
         }

         public String getKey() { return key; }
         public String getShortcut() { return shortcut; }
    }

    public enum B {
         MyField1("1", "2"),
         MyField4("7", "8"),
         MyField5("9", "10"),

         private final String key;
         private final String shortcut;

         B(String k, String s){ 
             this.key= k;
             this.shortcut= s;
         }

         public String getKey() { return key; }
         public String getShortcut() { return shortcut; }
    }

    public enum C {
         MyField1("1", "2"),
         MyField6("11", "12"),
         MyField7("13", "14"),

         private final String key;
         private final String shortcut;

         C(String k, String s){ 
             this.key= k;
             this.shortcut= s;
         }

         public String getKey() { return key; }
         public String getShortcut() { return shortcut; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary for them to be three enums and not just one? It's not clear from your example code.

Comment: Yes because according to the following enum, it iterates over it to get all key/shortcut related. Maybe the best way to do it is to create a general constructor ?

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces, sounds like a good place to put that into practice. That won't make your enum body any shorter, but it makes using them in a unified manner easier.

Comment: I saw some examples on the internet, thanks I'll definitely have a look!
I was wondering if this can be a better solution : create a TestObject class that contains key and shortcut fields, and another class where I create multiples TestObject, that will be associated to A, B etc. Do you see what I mean ?